# Как изменить тип колонки на serial?

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица с заполненными данными:

```
CREATE TABLE "Виплата"
(
  old integer NOT NULL,
  "Код_договору" integer,
  "Дата" timestamp(0) without time zone,
  "Сума_виплат" text,
  "Оплата" boolean,
  "Код" integer,
  CONSTRAINT "Виплата_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (old)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "Виплата"
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Обязательно нужно изменить тип колонки "Код" на serial! 
Обычным ALTER: `ALTER TABLE "Виплата" ALTER COLUMN "Код" type serial;`  не получается это сделать, потому что serial не тип  `ERROR:  type "serial" does not exist`  ! *Но сделать это очень нужно.*

**Каким способом можно это реализовать ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тип `SERIAL` аналогичен полю, значение которого устанавливается из последовательности.
    Поэтому делаем так:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE code_seq;
ALTER TABLE "Виплата" ALTER COLUMN "Код" SET DEFAULT nextval('code_seq');
```

Не знаю как на мове правильно будет `"Последовательность_коду"`, поэтому просто `code_seq`.
В `nextval()` передаётся строка с название последовательности, поэтому там одинарные кавычки должны быть.

Comment: А возможно ли еще и указывать с какой цифры нужно начинать считать  ? просто у меня уже есть запись с кодом 1, а оно опять с 1 начинает!

Comment: ALTER SEQUENCE code_seq RESTART WITH 123

Comment: спасибо вам!!!!